# How to create offscreen Texture and use it on Android with OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am very new in OpenGL.

How can I create an offscreen texture, so that I can get some Informations of it (e.g. PixelColor by clicking on view texture) ?

I tried many many things for example FBO, but it did't work. I have no imagination how to load the Bitmap to a offscreen texture and get information of it. I am very frustated :/

[image: Task]

**Edit:**
Took [this](http://opengles2learning.blogspot.de/2014/02/render-to-texture-rtt.html) Tutorial as Example, don't know if it fits to my problem. `createFramebuffer`

```
public void createFramebuffer(GL10 gl) {

    FloatBuffer uvBuffer2;
    int texture[] = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, texture, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0, texture[0]);

    float uvs2[] = {
               0.0f, 0.0f,
               0.0f, 1.0f,
               1.0f, 1.0f,
               1.0f, 0.0f
       };

    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uvs2.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    uvBuffer2 = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    uvBuffer2.put(uvs2);
    uvBuffer2.position(0);

    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GLES20.GL_BYTE, 0, uvBuffer2);

    //load image
    int idTest = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/testgroesse", null, mContext.getPackageName());
    Bitmap wood = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), idTest);

    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0, 0, wood, 0); 

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);

    //color picking background start
    ByteBuffer bytePickedColor = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    bytePickedColor.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    GLES20.glFlush();

    GLES20.glReadPixels(touchXint, touchYint, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytePickedColor);

    byte b[] = new byte[4];
    bytePickedColor.get(b);
    String key = "" + b[0] + " " + b[1] + " " + b[2] + " " + b[3];
    Log.d("Color_Farbe: ", key);
    bytePickedColor.rewind();
    //color picking background end
}
```

Comment: FBO is the way to do it. Post your code so we can see what might be wrong with it.

Comment: Posted my FBO, but I can't see any bitmap is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To oversimplify:

The FBO you created is a BUFFER that contains RGBA + 16-bit depth. By attaching a texture to it you can then reuse the texture as it will have the same RGBA data as the FBO. At the beginning the buffer itself is still empty, you still need to clear it and draw to it as with any other render buffer.

So to put the image/texture on to that buffer you need to create the texture (with that image) and draw a textured rectangle on this FBO.

It would seem this is not what you are after:

- "How can I create a offscreen texture?" What is an onscreen texture? All textures are offscreen.
- "get some Informations of it"? Of what, the texture?! There are basically 2 ways of creating the texture: first is with an image in which case rather lookup the texel from the source image. Second is by drawing which is the FBO procedure where you need to read pixels (try `glReadPixels`).
- "e.g. PixelColor by clicking on view texture" Clicking on what?! You can click on view/screen but not the texture. If you again need the sample of the rendered view that you see before you then all you need to do is read the pixels as described before.

It looks like all you are looking for is `glReadPixels` to get the colour values from the current buffer. If this is not the case please rephrase your question and explain what is your goal here.

Comment: Sorry couldn't try it. I will do it now and write the results. I want to click on the Screen(texture) which shows the first picture with the black bars. After that, I want to translate that click-coordinates to get the color of the second image(texture) with excactly the same position.

Comment: Kind of like colouring the first image with the second one where the user drags?

Comment: yes I want to color the first image with the second one's color.

Comment: You do not need any extra buffers or offscreen stuff for that. I suggest you to use a stencil buffer for this. When user clicks you draw a circle (large dot) on the stencil buffer. Then on draw method you draw the first image (background) normally and then the second one using a stencil buffer so that the second one will be drawn only where stencil is 1 (where user has been clicking).

Comment: Sounds like, I need more images to realize that? 

I replaced my `createFramebuffer` Method. It seems to catch the result I want. I'm creating the buffer now with the image(second colored image) I want. 
At first try I loaded the second texture with using `GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D` in my `createFramebuffer` Method. So however the second buffer was shown in the view. Then I changed all `GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D` to `GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0`. The result was, that the second image didn't show up, but it also didn't take the Color of the second image. So what can I do to use my Framebuffer with `glReadPixels`?

Comment: This is very hard to understand what you are doing now.. If you are still applying multiple frame buffers you should know you need to set the viewport for each of them. For the pixel read to work all you need is to bind the desired frame buffer. GL_TEXTURE0, GL_TEXTURE1... is used to have multiple textures at the same time, that means having 2 textures used in the same draw call (which you do not need) so you can not replace GL_TEXTURE_2D with it, it is a totally different thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56174/discussion-between-csnewb-and-matic-oblak).